# SVG Safari filter/animation bug

Tags: animation, svg, svg-filters

I'm having a problem with a SVG filter on a CSS animation in Safari.

http://codepen.io/robertjpotter/pen/AvzhL

The problem is that in Safari the filter is grabbing the color from the completed animation.  What I would expect, and what is occurring in Chrome and Firefox, is that the filter would grab the beginning animation color and then animate to the final color along with each .

I'm new to SVG, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There may be a way to kick Safari the right way to make this happen, but the easiest way to do this is either do the animation using JavaScript, or use SMIL inside the filter.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to redo your animation so it happens within the filter using the animate element. This *should* work on Safari/Mac - but I've only tested it on Chrome/Windows. I didn't convert your colors from HSL, so you should replace the .2/.1/.3 with the starting RGB values expressed as a percentage and the .8/.6/.8 values with the ending RGB values expressed as percentages. Use the "fakeSMIL" library for IE10+ compatibility (google for it).

```
<filter id="dropGlow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="coloredBlur"/>
     <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="coloredBlur"/>
         <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
    </feMerge>
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                           0 1 0 0 0
                                           0 0 1 0 0
                                           0 0 0 1 0">
    <animate attributeName="values" from="0 0 0 0 .2
                                          0 0 0 0 .1 
                                          0 0 0 0 .3 
                                          0 0 0 1 0" 
                                      to="0 0 0 0 .8 
                                          0 0 0 0 .6 
                                          0 0 0 0 .8 
                                          0 0 0 1 0" 
       begin="4s" fill="freeze" dur="1s"/>
          </feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
```